# I want to compress my files in vitejs react

Tags: reactjs, compression, vite

I want to compress my files in ViteJS and React. I used vite-plugin-compression and imported it:

```
import viteCompression from 'vite-plugin-compression';
```

```
plugins: [viteCompression({ algorithm: 'brotliCompress'}),
```

When i used :

```
npm run build
```

I get my files as index-123.js index-123.css and index-123.js.br index-123.css.br in assets and inside of my index.html. It uses .js file and even if i change it manually to .js.br and .css.br it won't work

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./assets/logo-d3a0dcae.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Name of Project</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-4402516d.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/index-85e30739.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

In line 8 changing .js to .js.br manually gives me this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6uzL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the newer plugin vite-plugin-compression2https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-compression2. It always worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the aforementioned `vite-plugin-compression2`.

I'm the author of the plugin. You won't need change your `index.html`. You just need a server to run it, only setting the HTTP response header is enough.

For details, see [content-encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding).